# Is there any portlet or plugins which can help me in the implementing live customer support chat?

Tags: jquery-plugins, portlet, liferay-7

I need to implement live customer support chat to liferay 7.
Portal will provide capability for the end user to chat with the support users for online issue resolution, technical and non technical help. Portal support team can support the end users over chat as well over E-mail for the first tracking issue resolution. The user will be provided with a hyper link at footer of each page to start Web Chat. Once the user clicks on Web Chat the Web Chat window will be opened for communication. User can put his/her e-mail id, issue category and queries to start Web Chat. Once the Web Chat will be initiated by user, one chat window will be opened at for support user who is logged in mediation portal to provide support. If the support team is not available, then the end user will be communicated with a message that, Customer support teat will be in touch with you soon on e-mail.  The user chat requests will be allocated among the support users those who are logged in mediation portal in round robin method.

Answer (score 0):

There is the native chat portlet, but I really do not recommend using it for your case, your case is a bit more complex then what comes out of the box. You will be better served if a support system plugin.

I like https://www.zendesk.com/chat/

Which is pretty easy to install and customize.

Comment: ps: if you have this license you can get an integration plugin: https://store.docker.com/images/esystemstech even if you don't use docker